# Dell N2000: How to capture PCAP to NVRAM?

Tags: dell, powerconnect, pcap

I have tried without success to capture to NVRAM on a Dell 2024. Here's what I have tried:

```
enable
configure
monitor capture file size 512
monitor capture mode file
exit

monitor capture start

<generate traffic ...>

monitor capture stop

copy flash://cpuPktCapture.pcap scp://<user>@<ip>/home/pi/cpuPktCapture.pcap
```

All the monitor commands execute without an error. The copy command generates:

```
ERROR: File cpuPktCapture.pcap not exist!
```

During capturing, `show monitor capture` shows:

```
g05hsw01#show monitor capture

Operational Status............................. Enabled
Current Capturing Type......................... File
Capturing Traffic Mode......................... Tx/Rx
Line Wrap Mode................................. Disabled
RPCAP Listening Port........................... 2002
RPCAP dump file size (KB)...................... 512
```

What am I doing wrong?

Related question: is there a way to get a listing of the files in the switch's file system?

Comment: "_is there a way to get a listing of the files in the switch's file system?_" As a wild guess, did you try `dir`?

Comment: Good God. Yes. That works. And there is a file called 'cpu-pkt-capture.pcap', which is not what it's called in the manual. FYI I cannot find a single instance of the word 'dir' in the entire 2300 page N2024 CLI reference guide. I have now been able to copy the capture file, which was saved but in different name to the one specified in the manual. Thank you!

Comment: I added it as an answer so that you can accept it, so that the question doesn't keep popping up, looking for an answer, forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying `dir` seems to have solved your problem, showing you the real file name.